# In AppScript, when multiple ranges are edited at once, How is rangeList obtained?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I wrote script for Google Sheets which is triggered by an `onEdit` event.

To ilustrate my problem, let's suppose that the contents of ranges `A3:A5`, `C3:C5` and `E1:E8` were selected and then deleted at once by pressing [delete]. In this situation, the `onEdit(e){...}` function would be called. The problem is that object `e` only has information about the first edited range: `e.range.getA1Notation() == 'A3:A5'`.

I tried obtaining the other edited ranges by calling `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveRangeList().getRanges();` but only the first range is being returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The way to do it would be:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var selection = e.source.getSelection(); 
  var ranges=selection.getActiveRangeList().getRanges();
  for (var i = 0; i < ranges.length; i++) {
  Logger.log(ranges[i].getA1Notation());
  }
}
```

However, only the first range will be returned if you run the function onEdit() instead of manually with `var selection = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getSelection();`.

This seems to be a bug and has already been filed on Issuetracker:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/115931946

I suggest you to give it a "star" to increase visibility.

Comment: Only the first range is being returned still. However, thanks for letting me know about the bug, just gave it a star.

Comment: Yes, only the first range being returned is exactly what the bug is about! Until it is resolved unfortunately you won't be able to get a range list on edit. You have to think about a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

- You want to retrieve all selected ranges when the OnEdit event trigger is fired.

  - In your case, when the cells of `A3:A5`, `C3:C5` and `E1:E8` are manually deleted, you want to retrieve the ranges of `A3:A5`, `C3:C5` and `E1:E8`.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several answers.

### Issue:

At first, I summarized the current situation as follows. As the sample case, it supposes the situation that the cells of `A3:A5`, `C3:C5` and `E1:E8` are deleted.

- The event object of OnEdit event trigger cannot return the values of multiple ranges like `A3:A5`, `C3:C5` and `E1:E8`.
- When the OnEdit event trigger is fired, the script of by running the trigger returns only `A3:A5` which is the first selected range.

  - The script is `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSelection().getActiveRangeList().getRanges()`.
- When the above script is run by the script editor, `A3:A5`, `C3:C5` and `E1:E8` are returned.

These were mentioned by XY6 and ziganotschka. I also think that this might be a bug.

From above situation, I guessed that when the OnEdit event trigger is fired, if the script is indirectly run by the trigger, `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSelection().getActiveRangeList().getRanges()` might return `A3:A5`, `C3:C5` and `E1:E8`. By this, I thought the following workaround.

### Workaround:

In this workaround, above my guess was achieved using a dialog. The flow of this workaround is as follows.

1. Cells of `A3:A5`, `C3:C5` and `E1:E8` on the Spreadsheet are manually deleted.
2. The installable OnEdit event trigger is fired and a script is run.
3. The script opens a dialog.

   - The side bar can be also used for this situation.
4. The script of `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSelection().getActiveRangeList().getRanges()` is run using Javascript at the dialog.

By this, running indirectly `getSelection` can be achieved. As the result, it was found that this workaround can retrieve all selected ranges when the OnEdit event trigger is fired.

### Sample script:

The sample script for this workaround is as follows. When you use this script, [please install `myFunction()` as the installable OnEdit event trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually).

```
function myFunction() {
  var script = "<script>google.script.run.withSuccessHandler((e)=>{google.script.host.close()}).getSelectedRanges()</script>";
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(script).setWidth(100).setHeight(100);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, "sample");
}

function getSelectedRanges() {
  var selection = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSelection().getActiveRangeList().getRanges();
  var ranges = selection.map(function(e) {return e.getA1Notation()});
  Logger.log(ranges) // ["A3:A5", "C3:C5", "E1:E8"]
}
```

- When the cells of `A3:A5`, `C3:C5` and `E1:E8` on the active Spreadsheet are manually deleted, a dialog is opened by `myFunction()`, and Javascript of the dialog runs `getSelectedRanges()`. Then, the dialog is automatically closed.

### References:

- [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)
- [Class Ui](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui)
- [Class HtmlService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-service)
- [Class Selection](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/selection)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.